# Accidentially 'instantiate' an abstract class type using brace-initializers?

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class

Today I stumbled over the following issue. Someone got a little too fond of brace-initializers and accidentally tried to instantiate an interface class. Bear with me:

```
#include <iostream>

class IFoo
{
public:
   virtual ~IFoo() = default;
   virtual bool getFoo() const = 0;
};

void processFoo(const IFoo &fooImpl)
{
    bool foo = fooImpl.getFoo();
    std::cout << "got foo " << foo << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   processFoo({});  // <- why is this valid?!
   return 0;
}
```

Until now I'd expected that the compiler would issue an error similar to the one you get when trying something silly like calling `IFoo()` or `IFoo{}`. However, the above code compiles without warning (on gcc 6.2) but will obviously terminate with '**pure virtual method called**' as soon as you try to invoke the `getFoo()` method. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52680e74c9e9ec39).

Could somebody kindly explain to me what is going on there?

Comment: Looks like this is a g++ defect.

Comment: gcc 5.1 compiles a simplified main `int main()
{
  const IFoo& foo = {};
   return 0;
}
`  sorry can't format comments.  ... also `const IFoo& foo{}; ` compiles

Comment: @djf it looks like clang 5.0.0 HEAD properly catches this error from testing on [melpon's online compiler](http://melpon.org/wandbox/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [known GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70939). Unfortunately, the issue is still open and not assigned to anyone, it seems.

Comment: They must be waiting for the standard to adopt some kind of default instantiation and Scala evidences to proclaim it a feature.

Comment: Thanks for digging up that link, Christian. I've been looking for known issues, but couldn't find anything pertinent : )